# Sharing pointers between two kernel modules

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver

I have created two kernel modules, module1 and module2
module 1 has a function 'foo':  int *foo(int a);   I have exported this function as a symbol and using this in module2.
My question is if I have allocated memory in module1's foo function dynamically and returned that pointer to module2, so can I free that memory in module2 ? If yes how this memory is freed by kernel because the address that is returned to module2 doesn't belong to its address space?

Comment: `by kernel because the address that is returned to module2 doesn't belong to its address space?` Makes no sense, kernel is not limited to a "address space". You can read and write to any memory, you are the kernel.

Comment: So in my example case we must not free that pointer in module1? We should always free it in module 2 since it is using it

Comment: Why do you want to do layering violation? If you need to free memory in module 2, simple export free function as well.